# textmate word selection and brackets

Tags: textmate

How can i make textmate selet the bracket if i put my cursor before some other like in notepad++ and how can i make i highlight all words in the document which are similar to the one i've selected and how cna i make it open all fiels in tabs and now new windows?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Edit>Select>Enclosing Brackets` (Shift-Cmd-B) will do what you would expect it to. I don't know how to highlight similar words, but if you select a word and choose `Edit>Find>Use Selection for Find` (Cmd-E) followed by `Edit>Find>Find Next` (Cmd-G), you can move through the words that match your selection. Regarding a tabbed window interface, this works when the files are within a [project](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_multiple_files).